# Get adjacent cell for the largest time if value found in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I have 3 columns with about 4000 rows and 4 other columns with about 60000 rows. I have to search for every name and get the last recorded exit from release column. I have tried with vlookup and max but it doesn't show the right record.

```
=MAX(LOOKUP(B2,H1:H6,OFFSET(I1:I6,0,1)))
```

SO if the name mike1 is found in column H and the date for mike 1 is the same as the found results then D2 must be equal with the case for the biggest hour for the results found.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a multiple criteria `Index/Match` with `Max()` perhaps?

Comment: for mike1 it does ok but form mike2 it gives me the mike7254 case